# What applications can create a video from an audio file and an image file(s)?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, video

I have an audio file, and an image file (or several image files). Which applications allow me to create a video that combine the audio and image files. For example, the audio file is a recording of reading a script, and the image file(s) is screenshot(s) of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/) on Linux. It's a free & open source video editor (non-linear).

In my opinion, Kdenlive has a nice GUI and if you have problems or don't know, how to do something, you can check the [docs](https://docs.kdenlive.org/).

Comment: Thanks. Can most video editing applications do the job?

Comment: @Tim Yes, they can.

Answer (score 1):

I use  [PhotoFilmStrip](https://www.photofilmstrip.org/en/features/) for such cases. It is much simpler (less powerful and less complicated) than Kdenlive.

Comment: Thanks. Can most video editing applications do the job?